# R Shiny make second action button 2 appear after action button 1 is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

I think I am missing something very simple.

I want my user to click on action button 1 so that action button 2 appears. But how can I 'render' a new action button in ui?

My code is below.
Thank you very much!

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("button1", label = "Press Button 1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # what should I write here?
      #renderPrint("button2")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    output$button2 <- renderUI({
      actionButton("button2", label = "Press Button 2")
    })
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `renderUI()` on server side, you have to use `uiOutput()` on the ui side.

**Full code reads:**

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("button1", label = "Press Button 1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # what should I write here?
      uiOutput("button2")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    output$button2 <- renderUI({
      actionButton("button2", label = "Press Button 2")
    })
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: A quick question - how can I refer to button2 going forward (e.g., to produce observeEvent dependent on button2? Can I still say: observeEvent(input$button2 ...? Or should I refer to it differently?

Comment: @user3245256 have you ever found out how to refer to button2? I ran into a similar problem. ObserveEvent of this button 2 does nothing. No clue how to solve it.